# process the files in S3 based on their timestamp using python and boto

Tags: python, datetime, amazon-s3, timestamp, boto

I am trying to process files in `S3` based on the timestamp that these files have. I have this code which provides me the `date modified` attribute of the files and I then parse it to convert it into appropriate format using `boto.utils.parse_ts`. Now I want to sort the files and if possible put their key name in a `list` in sorted order so that the oldest files comes first for processing. How can I do this?

```
con = S3Connection('', '')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket')
keys = bucket.list('folder1/folder2/')

for key in keys:
    date_modified = parse_ts(key.last_modified)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably lots of ways to do this but here's one way that should work:

```
import boto.s3
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('us-east-1')
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
keys = list(bucket.list(prefix='folder1/folder2/'))
keys.sort(key=lambda k: k.last_modified)
```

The variable `keys` should now be a list of `Key` objects which are sorted by the `last_modified` attribute with the oldest first and newest last.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am having one issue though. when I see the timestamp from `k.last_modified` I see different time than what I see if I go to S3. Does `k.last_modified` outputs time in different time zone? How can I convert it to say EST?

Comment: The timestamp stored in the S3 service should be in UTC.  When you say "if I go to S3" do you mean you go to the AWS Management console?  If so, it may be localizing the time to your timezone.

Comment: If the question is how to convert a timestamp to another time zone, I would suggest you use the ``pytz`` package.

Answer (score 2):

I used a dictionary and sorted the values.  This leaves you with the name and the last_modified if you need it.   Otherwise, a simple list is probably faster.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection()  # assumes region/keys setup in .boto
bucket = conn.get_bucket('mybucket')
dict = {key.name:key.last_modified for key in bucket.get_all_keys()}
dict = sorted(dict.items() key=lambda x: x[1]) # lambda sort order <
```

ex:

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
conn = S3Connection()
bucket = conn.get_bucket('cgseller-test')
dict = {key.name:key.last_modified for key in bucket.get_all_keys()}
print dict
>>> {u'newfolder/else': u'2015-04-01T01:33:43.000Z', u'newfolder/file': u'2015-04-01T01:23:51.000Z', u'newfolder/file1': u'2015-04-01T01:23:42.000Z', u'newfolder/file2': u'2015-04-01T01:23:34.000Z'}

dict = sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print dict
>>>[(u'newfolder/file2', u'2015-04-01T01:23:34.000Z'), (u'newfolder/file1', u'2015-04-01T01:23:42.000Z'), (u'newfolder/file', u'2015-04-01T01:23:51.000Z'), (u'newfolder/else', u'2015-04-01T01:33:43.000Z')]
```